# MySQLi connection with error

Tags: php, mysqli

Can you tell me where is my problem?

```
<?php
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "database") or die ("Problem!");
    $query = mysqli_query("set names utf-8", $connect);
    session_start();
?>
```

This part of code answer me with this:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given
>   in C:\xampp.......php on line 4

thanks for your help

Comment: code run away and i dont know why

Comment: @Leodiruk Add the code you're using to run the query.

Comment: `mysqli_query($connect,"set names utf-8");`. mysqli_query requires first parameter as connection and second as string

Comment: @Undefined_variable you are awesome... THANK YOU SO MUCH!!

Answer (score 3):

you wrong format

plz try like this

```
mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write `mysqli_query` in two ways.

Object oriented style

```
mixed mysqli::query ( string $query [, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ] )
```

Procedural style

```
mixed mysqli_query ( mysqli $link , string $query [, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ] )
```

According to your code you are using `Procedural style` with a wrong syntax. which should be

```
mysqli_query($connect,"set names utf-8");
```